# .subscribe is not working in my ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am ASP.NET MVC developer. I am new to Knockout js, currently I am using KO js in my application. Dropdownlist select change (.subcribe) is not working properly. Please find my code below:

My task is: There are three dropdownlists, I have to bind data to the next dropdownlist on change event of first dropdown list. 
[image]
script:

```
    var array_BankNames = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Banks));


    var Bank = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.BankName = ko.observableArray(array_BankNames);
        self.SelectedBank = ko.observable();

        self.BankLocation = ko.observableArray();
        self.SelectedLocation = ko.observable();

        self.BankBranch = ko.observableArray();
        self.SelectedBranch = ko.observable();

         self.SelectedBank.subscribe = function () {
            alert("Hi");               
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetBankLocations_Data")',
                data: { Bankname: selectedValue },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    self.BankLocation(data);
                }
            });
        }.bind(self);
    };

    var BanksModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Banks = ko.observableArray([new Bank()]);

        self.addBank = function () {
            self.Banks.push(new Bank());
        };

        self.removeBank = function (Bank) {
            self.Banks.remove(Bank);
        };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new BanksModel());
```

Html:

```
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-8 controls">                              
                              <select data-bind="
                                    options: BankName,
                                    optionsValue: 'ID',
                                    optionsText: 'Name',
                                    value: SelectedBank">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankLocation, new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-4 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-8 controls">

                            <select data-bind="options: BankLocation,
                            optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name', value: $root.SelectedLocation">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankBranch, new { @class = "col-sm-3 col-md-4 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-8 controls">

                            <select data-bind="options: BankBranch,
                                    optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name', value: SelectedBranch">
                             </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `.subscribe` should work fine . any errors in console ? lets us know . cheers

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.validation.min.js"></script> this reference showing error. so removed it. after removing that reference there are no errors in console.

Comment: As there are no errors , is subscribe firing now? if not remove all references(for time being) just place  jquery 1.9.js at start and next knockout-3.2.0.js and execute . hope it works

Comment: I did as you told, still no luck :(. it is still not firing.

Comment: well `ko.validation.js` showing error (may be) because it is referred before to  `knockout 3.2.js` . loading order is important .

Comment: why for second dropdown you using `$root` and nothing for dropdown1 `value` . what is your exact view structure (see i'm guessing everything here) a sample repro of you issue in fiddle will be helpful .

Comment: Hi Super cool, I have attached the image of my screen. Please have a look. I tried to add the code in fiddle, but I could not complete it, I m totally new to fiddle. Donno my code is not working in fiddle.

Comment: well image doesn't help the cause . believe me if you try to set up a fiddle there subscribe will fire for sure . i suggest you to debug like create a new textbox and make `data-bind="value=test"` then add respective observable self.test=ko.observable() and try self.test.subcribe=function(val){alert(val}): .. check when you eneter something and mousout the is subscribe firing or not lemme know .

Comment: Hi super cool, today i tried in fiddle its working and the link is: http://jsfiddle.net/MVCDeveloper/73Q79/22/. I am implementing in my project, let me check my luck. however in fiddle its working.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question:

```
self.LoadLocations = ko.computed(function () {
                var tempreview = self.SelectedBank();
                return tempreview;
            }),
            self.LoadLocations.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetBankLocations_Data")',
                    data: { Bankname: newValue },
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.BankLocation(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

This is the script for cascading drop down lists in my project.

Answer (score 0):

From the context of the AJAX callback, the model isn't `BanksModel`, it's `self`... so:

```
 self.SelectedBank.subscribe = function () {
    alert("Hi");
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBankLocations_Data")',
        data: { Bankname: SelectedBank() },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            self.BankLocation(data);
        }
    });
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetBankLocations_Data")', SelectedBank, function (data) {
        self.BankLocation(data);
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here the case is my screen is similar to shopping card screen (refer: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html). So I need to use self only, because there will be more than one control with the same name but different frame within the same screen.

Comment: spender is right need to use self . @MVCDeveloper `self.SelectedBank.subscribe=function(selectedValue){ //inside ajax data: { Bankname: selectedValue }}` . cheers

Comment: Thank you for helping me. My problem is .subscribe is not even firing. Please let me know if am missing any reference.                                   <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>                                         
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>, these are the references i kept. Is this reference problem or something else. Please let me know.